# DataGrid copy to clipboard DateTime format issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have a data grid in WPF that I am filling with an SQL query result through a data table. However, when I copy the grid to clipboard, it is always copied with the full date/time format. Here is what I am doing:

I have an SQL statement to read some data including date field from the DB as:

```
searchProDateSQLCMD.CommandText = "select pName, convert(date, pDate), FROM [Professionals] WHERE pName = @parName"
```

I fill a data table with the result as:

```
dTableAdpater = new SqlDataAdapter(searchProDateSQLCMD);
dTable = new DataTable("Professionals");
dTableAdpater.Fill(dTable);
```

I then set the column for the grid to display the info:

```
DataGridTextColumn jDateCl = new DataGridTextColumn();
pDateCl.Binding = new Binding("pDate");

pDateCl.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:d}";
```

I then bind the grid with the column I created

```
SearchResultGrid.Columns.Add(pDateCl);
```

When I try to copy that column:

```
SearchResultGrid.SelectAllCells();
SearchResultGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
```

I get the time copied; but with the time format is `(dd/MM/yyyy 12:00:00 AM)`, even though I use `convert()` in SQL, and `{0:d}` in the column.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing to just get the date on copy without the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a current `DataGrid`'s implementation limitation.

As you can see in the [reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGridClipboardHelper.cs,65569359e92a3fe0,references), the `DataGrid` renders the cell's contents into the clipboard using a simple `ToString()` call, without providing any format. This call will use the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and the default format for the `DateTime`, hence the result you get.

So you have at least two options:

- Set the main thread's `CultureInfo` to the the desired date/time format. Note that this will affect all the `ToString()` calls on any `DateTime` objects, so maybe this is not suitable for you.
- Instead of using a `DateTime` column, use a `string` column and do the conversion on the server side. Not a good approach however, because you loose all the benefits of the `DateTime` type.

Comment: I went with converting the column to string.